# Can't generate NodaZoneData file using NodaTime.TzdbCompiler

Tags: compiler-construction, nodatime

When I attempt to generate a NodaZoneData file using the NodaTime.TzdbCompiler and the latest IANA tzdb download, I receive the following output:

```
Starting compilation of directory data\2014f
Parsing file africa . . .
Parsing file antarctica . . .
Parsing file asia . . .
Parsing file australasia . . .
Parsing file backward . . .
Parsing file etcetera . . .
Parsing file europe . . .
Parsing file northamerica . . .
Parsing file pacificnew . . .
Parsing file southamerica . . .
Parsing file systemv . . .
Parsing file zone1970.tab . . .

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.InvalidDataException:
Unexpected zone database keyword: AD at ModaTime.TzdbCompiler.Tzdb.TzdbZoneInfoParser.ParseLine(String line, TzdbDatabase database)
```

The compiler appears to stop on the file zone1970.tab. If I remove that file. I can compile a NodaZoneData file without errors.

Comment: Out of interest, why are you building the file yourself? Is it to avoid having to fetch from the web site, or because you weren't aware of it? I normally push a new file within hours of it being announced on the tzdb list... this time it took a bit longer due to meetings and the new file, but it was still pretty quick. If there's some scenario where we could help you better so you didn't need to do this work yourself, I'd love to hear about it :)

Comment: Our requirements for using NodaTime include being be able to update the NodaZoneData file in the event that you, god forbid, fall off the face of the earth and a tz update is required. We're using NodaTime in a production system for rail industry. FWIW, it's working wonderful and was easy to use. I just need to complete this workflow of updating directly from iana tzdb.

Comment: Makes sense - it's good to hear of a "belt and braces" approach for once :) For the moment, with the 1.3 branch, deleting `zone1970.tab` manually is the simplest approach. If it would be useful for you if I added an extra commit to that branch to make `TzdbCompiler` ignore that file (as it does `zone.tab`), I'd be happy to do that. (Or just patch in [the 2.0 revision](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/source/detail?r=707440a36546dd04885553e65ede7ba4d71d6f41) to your local copy, of course.) Glad to hear it's working out for you - and we're always open to requests :)

Comment: No extra commit necessary. We can patch locally. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is due to `zone1970.tab` only being introduced in 2014f, and the released `TzdbCompiler` not knowing about it. Delete the file, and you should be fine - or you can just use the [nzd file we've already put up on the web site](http://nodatime.org/tzdb/tzdb2014f.nzd).

If you're brave enough to fetch the 2.0 codebase, `TzdbCompiler` has been fixed to expect `zone1970.tab` - and we've got an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/issues/detail?id=319) tracking the fact that we should support it properly at some point.

If you want to patch your local copy instead, [revision 707440a3](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/source/detail?r=707440a36546dd04885553e65ede7ba4d71d6f41) is the change that fixes it in 2.0. Basically you just need to add that file to the list of ones that `TzdbCompiler` ignores.

Comment: perhaps off topic, but what are the implications of NOT using zone1970.tab. To what degree will this effect tz accuracy? I'm primarily concerned with North America.

Comment: @Bruce: Unless you're using the `TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.ZoneLocations` property, it will make no difference whatsoever. It doesn't affect the time zones - just the metadata which could be useful for users to pick time zones. The `zone1970.tab` file groups regions which have effectively been in the same time zone since 1970 together.

Comment: I'm primarily using IDateTimeZoneProvider.GetZoneOrNull Method

Comment: @Bruce: It will make no difference to that at all. You're fine :)